# ScrollView doesn't scroll after orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a layout that starts like:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/Black"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >
```

I am using Fragments, and when I rotate the device scrolling doesn't work but the buttons at the top of the screen are still functional.

I am letting the activity restart on the orientation change, and I just repopulate all of my elements based on the arguments passed to the Fragment.

In my `onCreateView` I have this snippet:

```
if (getArguments() != null) {
    String s = getArguments().getString("bookId");
```

This allows me to then repopulate all of my elements if it isn't an empty string. The elements do get repopulated properly so everything works except the scrolling.

What may be the problem that prevents scrolling from working whenever I rotate the device?